# Probability - marbles without replacement

Tags: probability, statistics

Math is my weakest subject and I'm having a hard time trying to figure out what equation to use in this problem:

A jar contains 5 purple balls, 10 pink balls, and 7 blue balls. If 3 balls are to be drawn successively without replacement. What is the probability of getting 2 purple balls and 1 pink ball?

Ans: I tried doing (5/22)(4/21) & (10/22). But I don't think it's right... Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you’re drawing without replacement, you are in effect just choosing a $3$-element subset of the set of $22$ balls. All $3$-element subsets are equally likely to be chosen, so a straightforward way to solve the problem is to count the $3$-element subsets containing $2$ purple balls and one pink ball and divide by the total number of $3$-element subsets.

There are $\binom52=10$ different pairs of purple balls, and there are $10$ pink balls, so there are $10\cdot10=100$ possible $3$-element sets consisting of $2$ purple balls and one pink ball. There are

$$\binom{22}3=\frac{22!}{3!19!}=\frac{22\cdot21\cdot20}{3\cdot2\cdot1}=11\cdot7\cdot20$$

sets of $3$ balls, so the desired probability is

$$\frac{100}{11\cdot7\cdot20}=\frac5{77}\;.$$

You can also work the problem directly in terms of probabilities, but not quite the way you tried. What you calculated is the probability of drawing a purple ball followed by another purple ball followed by a pink ball. However, you can also get the desired outcome by drawing **purple-pink-purple** or **pink-purple-purple**. If you do the calculations, you’ll find that each of those outcomes also has probability

$$\frac{5\cdot4\cdot10}{22\cdot21\cdot20}\;,$$

so the actual probability is $3$ times that, or

$$\frac{3\cdot5\cdot4\cdot10}{22\cdot21\cdot20}=\frac5{11\cdot7}=\frac5{77}\;.$$

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Helped me a lot.

Comment: @Jeansilvy: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 3):

The number of ways to get the desired combination is:

$$\binom{5}{2}\cdot\binom{10}{1}\cdot\binom{7}{0}=100$$

The number of ways to get any combination of $3$ balls is:

$$\binom{5+10+7}{3}=1540$$

Hence the probability of getting the desired combination is:

$$\frac{100}{1540}\approx6.49\%$$

Comment: Wow that was fast! Thank you so much. You really helped me.